# Find and check the inverses (assuming they exist) of these block matrices:

Tags: linear-algebra

This is question 34 in section 2.5 of Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra textbook. The matrices are:

$\begin{bmatrix} I & 0\\ C & I \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} A & 0\\ C & D \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & I\\ I & D \end{bmatrix}$

How would you go about finding the inverse of block matrices in general? The instructors manual gives the following solutions, but there is no explanation as to how they were calculated:

$\begin{bmatrix} I & 0\\ -C & I \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} A^{-1} & 0\\ -D^{-1}CA^{-1} & D^{-1} \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} -D & I\\ I & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: forgot to mention: this is the 4th edition of the textbook!

Comment: Augmented matrix method?

Comment: Is it assumed that $A$ and $D$ are invertible?

Comment: What are your thoughts on finding the inverse?

Answer (score 1):

Let's do the first one. Let $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ be the inverse matrix, which means that $$\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ C & I \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}$$ Expanding the product (I assume that $I$ is the identity element of the field over which the matrices are defined) we get $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ aC + c & bC + d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}$$ This gives us a system of four equations in four unknowns, namely $$\begin{cases} a = I \\ b = 0 \\ aC + c = 0 \\ bC + d = I \end{cases}$$
Solving for $a, \: b, \: c, \: d$ (pretty easy) gives $a = I$, $b = 0$, $c = -C$, $d = I$, and thus the inverse is $\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ -C & I \end{bmatrix}$.

Now try the other ones by yourself using the same method.